# random result from db

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this php script in an external file trying to get random question from a db:

```
<?php
//connect to db
require_once('db.php');

$id=rand(0,13); //2nd number = highest ID

if ($resQ = $mysqli->query("SELECT Quest FROM qa WHERE ID='$id'")){

   echo "" . $resQ['Quest'] . ""; //This is Line 9

   $resQ->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

and I call it in my page like this

```
<body>
code...

<?php require_once('script/m_q.php'); ?>

...code
</body>
```

But i get error:

**Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in .../m_q.php on line 9**

Any help?
Thank you

**Thank you all... Unfortunatelly I can accept just one answer, si I choose the one that answered first.**

Comment: your not returning in any rows just running the query.

Comment: Have you ever considered to use some kind of ORM ?

Comment: Have you ever used ORDER BY RAND() for random results. No need to know how many entries there are in the database. Can be used with LIMIT 1 for just a single returned row.

Comment: @Pavlos1316 ORM - Object Relational Mapping, in it's implementation, some kind of PHP library used to abstract overall work with mysql/mysqli low api calls in php. Eg. **NotORM**,**Dibi**,**Doctrine**,etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqli::query does return a result set, you have to fetch rows in order to access the columns.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call the `fetch_assoc()` method of the `mysqli_result` object to access the data:

```
<?php
//connect to db
require_once('db.php');

$id=rand(0,13); //2nd number = highest ID

if ($resQ = $mysqli->query("SELECT Quest FROM qa WHERE ID='$id'")){

   $data = $resQ->fetch_assoc();
   echo "" . $data['Quest'] . ""; //This is Line 9

   $resQ->close();
}
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to fetch the data first.

```
$rs = $resQ->fetch_assoc();
echo $rs['Quest'];
```

Answer (score 0):

$resQ cannot get in an if statement... assign data to it 1st using mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_array.